# memory management while returning new pointer

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a method defined as

```
class1* class1::create(something)
{
    class1* a = new class1(*this);
    a->somemethod(something);
    return a;
}
```

which i call somewhere else as

```
class1* b = c::create(something);
```

so my question is will this leak memory? and if not why?

Comment: It will if you don't do `delete b;` at some point. it could also leak memory if the call to somemethod throws. Be safe, use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

Comment: Typically a factory method like this would be static and would be called like `class1::create`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will leak memory, unless the caller deleted `b`. Why? Because each call to `new` must be matched by a call to `delete`.

Note that this is a dangerous and exception unsafe pattern: it is better to return something that manages its own resources, and not place that onus on the caller. You could return a smart pointer (`std::unique_ptr` seeming to be the most suitable option), or just return a `class1` instance by value, instead of returning a pointer.

More on why it is a troublesome interface: A pointer can be many things in C++. It can be a pointer to an instance that you may or may not need to delete. It may be a pointer to the first element in an array, which may or may not be dynamically allocated. So the caller must know whether to call `delete`, `delete[]`, or nothing at all. That is without considering exceptions. If an exception is raised between the calls to `class1::create` and `delete b`, the object will not be deleted. Hence the importance of using a type that manages its own resources.

Comment: i dont have the liberty of not using pointer, but on larger scale i am getting a similar leak(i do delete it and no exceptions as far as i see)..and i cant solve it...note that i am using a copy constructor which in turn calls another copy constr. of parent.

Answer (score 0):

If eventually you will call `delete b;` it's not going to leak, otherwise it will be a leak.

Answer (score 0):

In case **no exception** is thrown, it will not leak memory nor will b point to an undefined place. Maybe you thought, that destructor of `class1` inside `create` will be called - this is not the case, only `class1 *a` is going to be removed from stack, and it is a built-in type. The `new class1` continues existing until you delete it explicitely.

But when an **exception** is thrown, there could be a memory leak, when `class1` allocates in its constructor dynamic memory and is *only* relying that it will be deallocated by destructor - this would not happen, since if `new class1` in your example fails, the destructor of `class1` is *not* called! Only the already allocated memory for the member variables of `class1` is removed from heap when `new class1` fails.

E.g.

```
class1* class1::create(something)
{
    class1* a = new class1(*this);
    a->somemethod(something);
    return a;
}
```

and

```
class1 *b = 0;
try
{
    b = c::create(something);
    delete b;
}
catch(...)
{
     delete b; // allright, no leak?
}
```

*isn't* guaranteed to be leak-free, if `class1` looks e.g. like this

```
class1
{
    int huge_var1[x][y][z];
    int huge_var2[x][y][z];
    int *huge_var3;
public:
    class1 (const class1 &c)
    {
        // bla bla bla
        huge_var3 = new int [x*y*z];
    }
    ~class1 ()
    {
        delete huge_var3;
    }
    // bla bla bla
};
```

When your `new class1` fails, `huge_var1` and `huge_var2` are deallocated from heap, but not the block where `huge_var3` points to.

Comment: There is only a leak when connection to this memory block is lost. It isn't, so it's not leaked memory, it's allocated-and-accessible memory.